# Proof - what is the name of this proposition?

Tags: proof-explanation

Can anyone tell me the name of this proposition, and give a proof it it is straightforward?

$$ \prod_{i\in I}(1+x_i)=\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J}x_j $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By induction:**

Let $I'=I\cup\{m\}$.

We have

$$\prod_{i\in I'}(1+x_i)=(1+x_{m})\prod_{i\in I}(1+x_i)=\prod_{i\in I}(1+x_i)+x_{m}\prod_{i\in I}(1+x_i).$$

On the other hand, as the subsets of $I'$ are those of $I$ without and with $x_{m}$,

$$\sum_{J\subseteq I'}\prod_{j\in J}x_j=\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J}x_j+\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J\cup\{x_{m}\}}x_j=\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J}x_j+x_{m}\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J}x_j.$$

The identity is vacuously true for $I=\emptyset$.

Comment: In the last line how can you write $\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J\cup\{x_{m}\}}x_j=x_{m}\sum_{J\subseteq I}\prod_{j\in J}x_j $ ?

Comment: @tam63: seems obvious from the range of the product, no ?

Comment: Sorry, I also cannot see how the first and second lines of your solution are equal?

Comment: yes sorry I can see that answer to my first question now

Comment: @tam63: by the inductive hypothesis. The statement is known true for $I$.